# How to stream windows 10 app through browser for user testing

Tags: uwp, aws-appstream, user-testing

I'm developing a UWP windows 10 targeted app. I'd like to get a few target users to test the app but I don't want to have to install on their computers.

I've looked at AWS AppStream but it seems like it only does Windows server 2012. I'm thinking about just setting up a virtual machine on a computer and allowing them to remote desktop in but that doesn't seem like a great solution.

What are some better ways to allow users to remotely access and test a Windows 10 app?

Comment: How will your target user test your apps? With Devops you may be able to also deploy to vms and add some simple test task to it. But actually it looks the same to build a VM. What do you expect here?

Comment: This is early user testing with some trusted contacts. They'll open the app, run through a few screens filling out some information and interpreting results. Nothing needs to be saved or communicate with anything. We'll have follow up calls/surveys to see how they felt about it afterwards. My main concern is that they may not be tech savvy users so in an ideal world I'd like to provide a URL they can go to, log in and see a desktop with our app. Today I tried just asking a user to remote desktop to a test PC I have and it worked OK but they were a little scared of remote desktop interface.